# Подключение геймпада к UWP проекту

Tags: c#, uwp

Есть `UWP` проект, к нему нужно подключить поддержку управления геймпадом(контроллер XBOX), как это можно реализовать? Есть ли какие-нибудь библиотеки или API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А родной апи от MS подойдет? :) 
[Документация UWP для джойстиков](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/gamepad-and-remote-interactions)